# Selenium fetches first 4 elements while scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Scraping code below only fetches 4 elements of "price", however once page is fully loaded there are 71 price related elements on the page.

Scraping code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


import pickle
import pandas as pd
import time

# Initializing a list with two Useragents 
useragentarray = [ 
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
] 

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.headless = True


web = "https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/womens-clothing"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setUserAgentOverride", {"userAgent": useragentarray[0]}) 

driver.get(web)
user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")

try:
    product_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'c-pwa-tile-tiles')))

except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Main container does not exist!')

prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@class="c-pwa-tile-grid s-pwa-tile-grid"]//span[contains(@class, "c-pwa-product-price__current s-pwa-product-price__current")]')))

print("Prices Length: ",len(prices))

product_name = []
product_price = []
book_length = []

for price in prices:
    product_price.append(price.text)
    
print("product_price => ", product_price)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

product_price =>  ['$130.00', '$42.00 – $52.00', '$19.00', '$69.00']

If I use XPATH in chrome like below, also again get 4 elements, however once I start iterating over it, it loads more elements related to "price"

[image]

Can you please guide as to how I can fetch all prices on the page, these should be ~71 as there are 71 products listed on the page, probably there is better implementing approach to this problem? perhaps scrolling over the page automatically?

Thanks for your expert input!

Answer (score 0):

intead of XPATH try to take a look class. For discount's page u can get all original prices using **class ="Price__originalPrice"**, and for current price **class"Price__currentPrice"**

Also, I'd like to suggest you use bs for getting price data. It'll be more efficient.